# Extract matched keyword for the text

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Looking for some help on extracting the keywords from the text. I have two data frame. The first dataframe has description column and the other data frame has only one column with the keywords.

I want to search the keywords from the dataframe2 on the description field and create a new column in dataframe1 with the matched keywords. If there are multiple keywords I need the newly added column with all the keywords seperated with comma as mentioned below.

Dataframe2

```
Keywords
New
FUND
EVENT 
Author
book
```

Dataframe1

```
ID  NAME    Month   DESCRIPTION              Keywords
12  x1       Jan    funding recived            fund
23  x2       Feb    author of the book     author, book
14  x3       Mar    new year event         new, event
```

Also, I need the keywords even the description has complete word. I.e Funding where I can get the keyword fund in the new column.

Comment: You may need `fuzzyjoin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin` and do a `group_by` concatenation (`paste`)

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   regex_left_join(df2, by = c('DESCRIPTION' = 'Keywords'), 
              ignore_case = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(ID, NAME, Month, DESCRIPTION) %>% 
   summarise(Keywords = toString(unique(tolower(Keywords))))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   ID, NAME, Month [?]
#     ID NAME  Month DESCRIPTION        Keywords    
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <chr>       
#1    12 x1    Jan   funding recived    fund        
#2    14 x3    Mar   new year event     new, event  
#3    23 x2    Feb   author of the book author, book
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(12L, 23L, 14L), NAME = c("x1", "x2", "x3"
), Month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), DESCRIPTION = c("funding recived", 
"author of the book", "new year event")), .Names = c("ID", "NAME", 
"Month", "DESCRIPTION"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Keywords = c("New", "FUND", "EVENT", "Author", 
"book")), .Names = "Keywords", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this and everyting works well as expected. However, just want to know if have more number of columns in my dataframe1 and is there a way that I can retain all the columns in my new dataframe where the keywords is getting added

Comment: @ssan As we are using left_join, it should all the columns in the 'df1' along with the newly added column

Comment: @ssan I guess you meant the `group_by` step?

Comment: Yes, but is that because we are using group by, it gives me the list of column mentioned in the group by alone

Comment: @ssan In that case, we can do a `right_join` with the 'df1' i.e. `%>% right_join(df1)`  (if I understand you correctly)

Comment: Are you saying like this... df1 %>% 
   right_join(df2, by = c('DESCRIPTION' = 'Keywords'), 
              ignore_case = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(ID, NAME, Month, DESCRIPTION) %>% 
   summarise(Keywords = toString(unique(tolower(Keywords))))

Comment: @ssan No, I meant `df1 %>% 
    regex_left_join(df2, by = c('DESCRIPTION' = 'Keywords'), 
               ignore_case = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(ID, NAME, Month, DESCRIPTION) %>% 
    summarise(Keywords = toString(unique(tolower(Keywords)))) %>% right_join(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be to use `stringr::str_detect` to check presence of `Keywords` in each `DESCRIPTION`.

```
library(stringr)

df1$Keywords <- mapply(function(x)paste(df2$Keywords[str_detect(x, tolower(df2$Keywords))],
                                        collapse = ","), df1$DESCRIPTION)

df1
#   ID NAME Month        DESCRIPTION    Keywords
# 1 12   x1   Jan    funding recived        FUND
# 2 23   x2   Feb author of the book Author,book
# 3 14   x3   Mar     new year event   New,EVENT
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 
"ID  NAME    Month   DESCRIPTION      
12  x1       Jan    'funding recived'   
23  x2       Feb    'author of the book'
14  x3       Mar    'new year event'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = 
"Keywords
New
FUND
EVENT 
Author
book",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```